# Windows wakes up by itself and starts spinning the fan until I bring up the login screen

Tags: windows-10, sleep

When I have put my windows 10 computer in sleep mode by pressing

<kbd>windows</kbd><kbd>X</kbd> → shut down or sign out → Sleep

It is more a rule than an exception that when I wake up in the morning,

- The computer has woken up by itself.
- The fan is spinning with high intensity.
- The fan slows down when I press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to get the login screen

What is this?

Comment: What is the output from running `powercfg -devicequery wake_armed` in a `cmd` shell? Please [edit] and add to the question.

Comment: Deep-scan your computer with Windows Defender and [Malwarebytes](https://www.malwarebytes.com/).

Comment: Update both BIOS and Power Drivers (Use the manufacturer's Driver Update App to update all drivers).

Comment: NONE @DavidPostill

Comment: Already updated drivers with Driver Easy. @John

Comment: The computer had this behavior from the beginning. Also I am continuosly running windows defender. Isnt that enough? @harrymc

Comment: It's good, but not enough to ensure that the computer is clean now.